# Master/Worker pattern - query worker about progress?

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a master/worker setup with one master node and many worker nodes. After finishing (can take a lot of time, maybe even up to an hour) the workers report back the results (the workers create images and, over time, add more and more details to it). So far so good.

Now we want to add another feature: the master process should be able to query the current image (i.e. the current progress) from the worker at any given time. How to do that? Are WCF callbacks with a duplex contract the way to go? Is this even suitable for such long-running tasks? Do we need to create a second WCF service on the worker side which gets the information from the worker thread somehow?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949427/effective-pattern-for-getting-progress-info-about-a-method-that-takes-a-long-tim?rq=1

Comment: Are you sure the linked question helps? Yes, I know about duplex contracts, however, are they suited if the response-communication is some hours later?